# Java Bazel Build Error : java/toolchains/bootclasspath_classes/DumpPlatformClassPath.class [for host] failed: not all outputs were created or valid

Tags: java, bazel, bazel-rules, bazel-java

Getting following error while building java bazel project -->

```
$ bazel build :all
INFO: Invocation ID: f3087fe5-67a5-4b0f-a3a8-a61b3bbfa869
WARNING: /home/ess/.cache/bazel/_bazel_ess/4fc692f493f73198611cffef8bfaa09d/external/cayman_zlib/BUILD.bazel:77:11: in linkstatic attribute of cc_library rule @cayman_zlib//:zlib: setting 'linkstatic=1' is recommended if there are no object files
INFO: Analyzed 23 targets (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured).
INFO: Found 23 targets...
ERROR: /home/ess/.cache/bazel/_bazel_ess/4fc692f493f73198611cffef8bfaa09d/external/prj_build/java/toolchains/BUILD:13:14: output 'external/prj_build/java/toolchains/bootclasspath_classes/DumpPlatformClassPath.class' was not created
ERROR: /home/ess/.cache/bazel/_bazel_ess/4fc692f493f73198611cffef8bfaa09d/external/prj_build/java/toolchains/BUILD:13:14: Action external/prj_build/java/toolchains/bootclasspath_classes/DumpPlatformClassPath.class [for host] failed: not all outputs were created or valid
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.794s, Critical Path: 0.43s
INFO: 3 processes: 1 remote cache hit, 2 internal.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

how can I resolve this bazel build issue?
Bazel version I am using is `4.0.0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting bazel toolchain and updating `.bazelrc` file with below contents solved my issue ---->

```
$ cat ~/.bazelrc
startup --server_javabase=/build/toolchain/lin64/jdk-1.8.0_201

startup --host_jvm_args=-Xms2G
startup --host_jvm_args=-Xmx2G

build --remote_http_cache=http://127.0.0.1:9090
build --remote_upload_local_results=true
build --remote_timeout=15
```